# High CPU Usage, system and svchost

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, cpu, cpu-usage

My pc has been experience lag ever since it came back from a fan upgrade.
Now i noticed that my cpu usage spikes from 10% to 80% and back in seconds, i see that svchost.exe is consuming 25% and system is spiking from 0% to 25% (i have 4 cores so it basicly consumes one core each). Does anybody has any idea of what to do?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I installed update KB3102810 and it partialy solved the problem,svchost does not spike anymore but System still spikes, meanwhile i noticed that in the services MsMpSvc, spikes up to 17%.

Comment: svchost is the process that manages services. Does your fan have any drivers that possibly run as service? If so, see if disabling that service solves your issue. Alternatively, install Process Hacker (taskmanager) to see which service is eating up your CPU usage and work from there.

Comment: My fan does not have any drivers.

Comment: this is WindowsUpdate. Check my answer in the duplicate link how to resolve this. With The installed June Updaterollup search takes less than 1 minute.

Comment: I actually updated yesterday and it is still spiking. Also sometimes MsMpEng also spikes.

Comment: MsMpEng = Windows Defender/Microsoft Security Essentials. Use a different antivirus tool, the one from Microsoft is slow garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify which service is causing it. First go into Services. Type it in the start Menu, or enable administrative tools in the start menu if it's not there already. Under services group them by which is running and see if there's any third-party, not windows service. You can stop and disable that.

If you don't find anything unusual there, download Process Explorer from Win Internals and see which servicehost is causing the abnormal CPU usage. If you double click on that one it should show you which services it is running. The services have a short name so you would have to google if it's not obvious which one it is. Once you know the culprit you go from there. If it's third party, disable it, if it's a Microsoft service then you will have to research why it could be doing that.